# Strange results in mersenne.org database

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, online-resources

I am interested in GIMPS project. I was browsing through [known Mersenne prime numbers](http://www.mersenne.org/primes/) when I discovered strange records in their database.

For example, M6972593 is the 38th Mersenne prime. However, [here](http://www.mersenne.ca/exponent/6972593) one can see L-L residue `B96EDBC2C1D0A3__` was reported. Another example is M13466917.

What is wrong here? Are some records reported in the GIMPS databases incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from elsewhere on this:

Records from that era (i.e. 10+ years ago) are sometimes incomplete. The actual is-prime LL results are missing from the database. In the case of both of the exponents in the question, some anonymous user ran an LL check but their hardware was faulty and they came up with a false-negative result.